# are these ideas about electromagnetism correct?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

A static electric charge produces a static electric field.

If the charge starts moving with constant velocity it will produce a magnetic field as well as the electric field. Together these make the electromagnetic field. This is a static field and will not propogate as EMR.

If the charge is accelerating (in a straight line or oscilating) then there will be changing electric and magnetic fields close to the source and these will propagate as EMR.

If you move at a constant speed  relative to a static electric charge it will produce a magnetic field as well, which collectively is the electromagnetic field from your point of view. Someone who is stationary will only see the electric field (if this is true why?). Also if you are accelerating the fields will propogate from your point of view but not a stationary point of view.

Thanks for your help

Comment: -1. Not useful (for the broader community). Asking for someone to check your understanding does not make a good question for this site. If there is some reason to doubt your that your understanding is correct, eg because it conflicts with something else, then that would make a good question (if it has not been asked already).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> A static electric charge produces a static electric field.

The electron - as well as the proton and their antiparticles - is surrounded by an electric field and a magnetic dipole moment.

> If the charge starts moving with constant velocity it will produce a magnetic field as well as the electric field. Together these make the electromagnetic field. This is a static field and will not propogate as EMR.

If a charge is moving without acceleration it is surrounded again by the same fields. The charge doesn’t emit electromagnetic radiation.

> If the charge is accelerating (in a straight line or oscilating) then there will be changing electric and magnetic fields close to the source and these will propagate as EMR.

A charge radiates photons - what is the same as to say it radiates EMR - under acceleration, which can be a change in velocity as well as forced movement in circles ([Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force)).

> If you move at a constant speed relative to a static electric charge it will produce a magnetic field as well,...

The static charge obey the same two intrinsic fields as described above. *If* electrons magnetic field would gain strength, the electric field should lose strength. This seems impossible due to the knowledge that the electric charge is of a constant strength.